# Batch script 2 options to change date for Windows 8

Tags: date, batch-file

Objective: set two options to change and then revert date depending on which one works.

Background: Intended for an obsolete Windows p2p app from 2005; company closed in 2006. This version was free to download and use for a limited time. Thus date needs to be changed back for several seconds before it's launched. There is a large community of people who use this program. ie: this is a community project.

History of this project: One technique (%BEFOREDATE%) works fine for Win 2K to Windows 7. Another technique (%CURDATE%) works fine for Windows 8 but not earlier. Recently someone noted the 1st technique does work on their Win 8 but not %CURDATE%, the opposite of my Win 8.

I discovered reverting of date to today produces some kind of error even though it succeeds which was sending it to the error-handling part (error handler quits the processes. Basically same as EXIT anyway.)

When the wrong option runs the program/script just hangs.

How to write this properly so it handles either of the options and does not hang if it comes across the one that does not work for that particular system?
I do not know what error is produced when the date changes correctly.

Portion of code that deals with the Win 8 options:

```
:ver_8
SET BEFOREDATE=%date:~4,2%-%date:~7,2%-%date:~10,4%
FOR /F "TOKENS=1* DELIMS= " %%E IN ('DATE/T') DO SET CURDATE=%DATE%
DATE 07-01-05
@echo off
PING -n 5 127.0.0.1 > NUL 2>&1
@echo off
DATE %BEFOREDATE%
ping -invalid-arg || goto :ver_2
goto exit

:ver_2
DATE %CURDATE%
ping -invalid-arg || goto :error
goto exit
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The earlier solution is below.

This solution is not clever but should work in most locales. Someone with a different date format can duplicate another line below this one:

```
if not "%format:mm-dd-yy=%"=="%format%" set olddate=07-14-2005
```

and change the mm-dd-yy to what the batch file reports in their different locale and the static date format to match it.

```
@echo off
for /f "delims=" %%a in ('echo.^|date^|find /i "current"') do set "d8=%%a"
for /f "delims=ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZabcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz: " %%a in ("%d8%") do set "d8=%%a"
for /f "delims=" %%a in ('echo.^|date^|find /i "Enter"') do set "format=%%a"
set olddate=

echo if this fails then add another line in the batch file and change the mm-dd-yy
echo to what you see at the at the end of this line below
echo %format% ^<---- here

if not "%format:dd-mm-yy=%"=="%format%" set olddate=14-07-2005
if not "%format:mm-dd-yy=%"=="%format%" set olddate=07-14-2005

:: to add a locale duplicate the line above and change the mm-dd-yy and static date as needed

date %olddate%

start "" "c:\folder\launch program.exe"

timeout /t 5 /nobreak
date %d8%
pause
```

**Original solution below:**

This works here in Windows 8 English.
It sets the date to todays date in the year xx05 and launches the program and resets the date to today again.

If you want a static date in 2005 then change `date %d8:~0,-2%05` but the date format will then be a factor for various locales - but this batch file does expect the year to be the last digits in the date string.

```
@echo off
for /f "delims=" %%a in ('echo.^|date^|find /i "current"') do set "d8=%%a"
for /f "delims=ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZabcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz: " %%a in ("%d8%") do set "d8=%%a"
date %d8:~0,-2%05

start "" "c:\folder\launch program.exe"

timeout /t 5 /nobreak
date %d8%
```

Comment: Thank you, I've tested it on Win 8 and works well for simply the date test but have not yet tested the launch (I removed the launch from my above example to simplify the sample.) Out of curiosity also tested on Win XP and worked also. So that would save a system check at start of the script.  * I've sent an exe version to the person who told me the other technique worked for them, so I will await their response to see if it is indeed a universal Win 8 answer, my guess is yes. Just one question, how would I specify a specific day and month in the above script you gave?

Comment: change `date %d8:~0,-2%05` to `date 14/07/2005` but use the right format for your machine.

Comment: wow that was fast lol. I don't suppose there is a way to make it a universal date? I realise different locales or even personal settings may re-order the format.

Comment: Feedback was it works on their system which means this is a universal Win 8 approach. WTG. I made an error in my previous comment. It either does not work with Win XP or is inconsistent. But Win 8 is the issue here. Thank you for both the fast & clever responses to all my questions. A+++ Unfortunately I do not have enough reputation to give your answer a major + ... anyway, question solved. TYVM for your time and excellent effort

Answer (score 0):

If you are not 'The Administrator' of the machine you need to 'Run as administrator' to set the date.  Note that just being an administrator is not enough.

Comment: Thanks for your response, yes I am aware of this and such information was included in the instructions for users. When converting to exe the requirement for admin is set.

Answer (score 0):

#### Some Notes:

This is saving the Date in format mm-dd-yyyy  (Note that some versions of Windows Date command takes in the format mm-dd-yy)

```
SET BEFOREDATE=%date:~4,2%-%date:~7,2%-%date:~10,4%
```

Try changing this to

```
SET BEFOREDATE=%date:~4,2%-%date:~7,2%-%date:~12,2%
```

What is the point of the for loop if you are just setting CurDate to Date?

```
FOR /F "TOKENS=1* DELIMS= " %%E IN ('DATE/T') DO SET CURDATE=%DATE%
```

Comment: That approach works fine on Win XP, but not on my Win 8. I found the %CURDATE% approach elsewhere on this site and is the only one that worked on my Win 8. If it needs to be adjusted then I'm a little ignorant to know what needs to be done.